# WordPress Get Header and Footer using in Admin Area

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, headers, footer

I was wanting a way to get the site header and footer and use it in the admin area.

Idea #1 An [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73534/73579) to another related question states to use an iframe instead I think we can use an [ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927573/get-another-pages-content-in-a-variable-with-ajax) get the header and footer from homepage and store in a function.

Idea #2 Where with jQuery we can clone() them, then store them in a function to use in the admin.

Maybe we need even both, I just think it's possible. I've seen a [familiar post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/add-header-and-footer-to-wp-backend) but still doesn't answer the question properly.

[This is a close](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84281/73579) start:

```
add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'insert_header_wpse_51023' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'insert_footer_wpse_51023' );
add_filter( 'admin_print_styles', 'footer_hide_wpse_51023' );

function insert_header_wpse_51023()
{
    echo '';
}

function insert_footer_wpse_51023()
{
    echo '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple experiment...

```
add_action('admin_init','get_header');

add_action('admin_init','get_footer');
```

... will demonstrate that the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions work on the back end as well as the front, though you will need to adjust for numerous markup problems and other issues.

Honestly, you question seems to be "how do I get the site header and footer and use it in the admin area?" but you don't say how you want  to use it, or why. Those are important considerations. As demonstrated, the "getting" is easy.

Comment: so do I add this code in the functions php file?

Comment: I added it there WordPress had connection issues. I edited your answer with different hooks, thanks